# ui-router nested state won't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is a pretty standard question, however I can't seem to find a solution in anything online. Below is the router/index.html page I'm using. I'm not getting any errors in the console, however when the url resolves, correctly, to the login page the entire page is blank. Any ideas, looking at the code below, as to what I'm missing?

**router**

```
(function(){
    'use strict'

    var app = angular.module('app.core');

    app.config(AppRouter);

    AppRouter.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

    function AppRouter($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
        $stateProvider
            .state('main', {
                url: '/main',
                abstract: true,
                resolve:{
                    Config: 'Config',
                    config: function(Config){
                        console.log(Config);
                        return Config;
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('main.login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
    }
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="slide-animation-container">
    <div ui-view id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>
    {{scrollTo}}
</div>
```

**login.html**

```
<div class="container" ui-view>
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
            <form id="loginForm" class="form-signin" style="max-width:300px;" autocomplete="off" ng-if="attemptLogin">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading" style="font-size:22px">Please Sign In</h2>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name" ng-model="user.username" required>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

The router above resides in my `config.js` file for my core module:

**core.module.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict'

    angular.module('app.core', ['angulartics', 'angulartics.google.analytics', 'angulartics.scroll', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ng.deviceDetector', 'ui.router',
                               'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTable', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCsv', 'toastr', 'angular.chosen', 'rzModule', 'publicServices']);
})();
```

Comment: You are not setting the ```templateURL``` pointing to `index.html` in your abstract route. Besides you need to inject `ui.router` in your app module declaration.

Comment: I need to set a `templateURL` even though it's an abstract state?

Comment: can you make an example (e.g. in [plunker](http://plnkr.co), [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), etc.)? I tried [making a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CfjZhg3IBbRINOjS6bz2?p=preview) but am not sure which versions of those libs you are using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `otherwise` logic changes the url to `/login` when no states match.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

However, your state definitions do not have a url that matches `/login`.

Because `main.login` is a child of `main`, it inherits the URL from `main`.
Therefore, you should use the full URL for `main.login` in your `otherwise()` call.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your module should have injected ui.router as a dependency ,

```
 var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router']);
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/2aR0aAIjTIWrfCMM7Njq?p=preview)**

Comment: Sorry, updated my post. I inject the `ui.router` in my `core.module.js` file